# Grails unit test not resolving class from plugin

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I have a grails application that uses a proprietary local plugin. In that plugin I've defined a class that extends Spock's `Specification` class (I use Spock for my unit tests), with some auxiliary methods to create fixture data for my unit tests. So, instead of extending `Specification` in my application's unit tests, I'd like to extend `MySpecification`. The problem is that if I do so, when running the unit tests it can't resolve MySpecification class and throws the following error:

```
Compilation error compiling [unit] tests: startup failed:
/Users/jesus/dev/myapp/test/unit/com/mycompany/FooSpec.groovy: 7: 
unable to resolve class com.mycompany.myplugin.MySpecification
 @ line 7, column 1.
   import com.mycompany.myplugin.MySpecification
   ^
```

`MySpecification`class is defined in the folder `/myplugin/test/unit/com/mycompany/myplugin/MySpecification.groovy`, and the plugin folder is located locally in the same folder than `myapp`.

I also define the plugin location in the file `/myapp/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` like this `grails.plugin.location.'myplugin'='/path/to/myplugin'`

The grails version is `2.5.5`

Isn't it possible to do that in grails with Spock?

Comment: In which folder you defined this class?

Comment: @EliasMedeiros I've updated the question with the information that you request

Comment: I suspect it's because you've created your class under test folder and it's not exported by the plugin. But if you move it out of test folder, you can't extend Specification... Can you use a trait instead of a class?

Comment: Yeah, I suspect the problem should be something related to what you say because I have source classes that extend base classes from the plugin and they're running properly. About moving the class out of the test folder, I think it's not a good design decision as the class is part of the test suit. I would prefer to make the plugin export that class if possible.